# How to align the Facebook comment box plugin in HTML

Tags: html, css, facebook-comments

I want to add a Facebook comment box plugin on my website.
I am using HTML.

So far, I have added the code to my website. 
The result looks good but the plugin is aligned to the left.
Is there any way I can use CSS/HTML to align is right at the center of my page?

plugin code:
`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mywebsite.com/mypage" data-numposts="5" data-width="" data-mobile="true"></div>`

This is the plugin I am referring to: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Please help me and tell me what I should do.
Also, pardon any mistakes in the question and let me know if I should add any more info.
Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Do you wanted to align it to right?

Comment: Hey, sorry if  I confused you. I want to align it to the center of the page. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to center it you can do the following

```
.fb-comments{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey, your code was almost right on point. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.fb-comments{
    position: absolute !important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 550px;
}
```